# My companions have all disappeared during boss battle

Tags: ps4, dragon-age-inquisition

If I've lost my companions and end up in an unwinnable boss battle, what are my options?

I am doing the part where you aim to get the Templars assistance. Not going to give anything more than that away but essentially I've got no help in the main fight, so I'm going through 8 potions and despite some weird jumping technique to avoid being floored, it's almost impossible to do any damage as a close-quarters combatant.

How can I fix this?

Prior to this part starting, the PS4 crashed with a blue screen. When I started it up again, I carried on where I left off, but I suspect it might be corrupt somehow.

Comment: I'm completely ambivalent in regards to publisher/developer, this game has fewer bugs than Skyrim based on the 10 hours I've played so far. I've just hit a sledgehammer of an issue unfortunately. I'm not sure how relevant your comment is tbh ;) - however I'd urge you to try the game, it "was" really good (until today!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to resolve this was to 'start over' or visit an old save and go from there.

Unfortunately I think the game causing a hard crash corrupted something which was irrecoverable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with that part of the game (I think I took the other route ;) but usually in battles where you are outmatched, you can just run away. Once you are far enough away, you should  "disengage" and be able to fast travel to safety. Running into a camp or town also usually helps. If you have party members still alive you should command them to disengage so they run with you and don't kite the enemy to you (using voice commands on xbox I just shout "everybody disengage", helps with a dragon or two I wasn't ready for yet).

I haven't encountered many battles where I was locked into an area and couldn't run away, although it often feels like that is the case based on the urgency of the plot that is happening around you. Although I haven't tried running away from every battle so maybe there are some. If you are truly locked in an area, then you have 2 options remaining.

First, I would look back at your saves. Sometimes (often) there is an autosave not long before you got into trouble. Use that, then fast travel to a more level-appropriate area.

The last suggestion I would have if all else fails, is to change the difficulty to easiest (you can change this setting mid game any time and change it back later), grind through the part, then get out of there.

Once safe you should probably go somewhere else and level up a bit more. I have found this game to have a lot of guesswork in terms of what level you should be at for an area, but it hasn't bothered me too much so far. As long as I can come back to it later; plus usually when that happens it means you're skipping a more fun new area that is level appropriate, so I go back and look for that.

Comment: Thanks - in this part, you're locked to a small area and the boss battle. I had another save which also had the same issue, so I dropped back to one that was 2 hours old and carried on from there, only I'm not going back to the main questline just yet!